Tweepy search on X (Twitter) keeps returning 401 Unauthorized error
I'm trying to retrieve some sample recent tweets from X using Python's Tweepy package. I am authenticating my API call with API Key, API Key Secret, Access Token, and Access Token Secret generated from a developer project within my own X account.
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)

query = <query-string>
client.search_recent_tweets(query=query)

But I keep getting Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized error.
I tried app-only authentication using my X Bearer Token but got the same error.
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=os.environ.get('BEARER_TOKEN'))

Note that this issue is occurring with Twitter API v2 which has replaced v1.1. This question has been asked before within the last year or so: here and here but there are no answers on either thread.
In case you do not have a resolution for the 401 error, suggestions for alternative Python packages for retrieving tweets from X are also welcome.

Didn't Twitter disable this functionality after the hostile takeover?

@tripleee If you could confirm that that is the case for sure I will give up now instead of trying to look for errors in my code!

Maybe a red herring, sorry. https://www.tweepy.org/ certainly looks like they claim to be up to date with whatever X offers.

I can now confirm that the issue is related to X (Twitter) policy and not the code posted above. As of Feb 2023 X Developers stopped supporting tweet search under the free API.

The Twitter API Documentation at https://developer.x.com/en/docs/twitter-api also makes it clear that the free tier access does not allow searching for tweets. Historical data prior to Feb 2023 can be obtained from the internet archive but not live data from X.
